# Can we use count(*) in pagination rather then using count to get number of records in the table?

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

Below is the  code, here i have used "select count(*) from departments" rather then using "select * from departments" so where am i wrong in this code. Can anyone help me out to sort it..

```
$num_rec_per_page=5;
    if (isset($_GET["page"])) { 
        $page  = $_GET["page"]; 
    } else { 
        $page=1; 
    }; 
    $start_from = ($page-1) * $num_rec_per_page; 
    $sql_query =  "SELECT * FROM departments LIMIT $start_from, $num_rec_per_page";
        $result = $db_connection->query($sql_query);
        if($result->num_rows > 0){
            while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                 echo "<tr>";
                 echo "<td>".$rows["id"]."<td>";
                 echo "<td>".$rows["name"]."<td>";
                 echo "<tr>";
            }
        }
        $sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM departments";  //select query for total records
        $rs_result = $db_connection->query($sql); //run the query
        $total_records =$rs_result->num_rows;  //count number of records
        $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $num_rec_per_page); 

        echo "<a href='index.php?page=1'>".'|<'."</a> "; // Goto 1st page  

        for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
            echo "<a href='index.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> "; 
        }; 
        echo "<a href='index.php?page=$total_pages'>".'>|'."</a> ";
```

Comment: What were you trying to do?
Select count(*) would yield the number of rows. Where as select * would simply select all

Comment: ya your right. Think i have 1000 records in the table, i don't want entire table to get fetched instead i just need no records in the table which will help me out in pagination. Did i make you clear.

Comment: whtas wrong in this ?? i mean are you getting an error??

Comment: i just changed count(*) to know no records instead select * ,by keeping in mind that table may contain 10,000 records so instead of fetching entire table i thought total number of records information will be better programming practice.

Comment: ya almost your right.

Comment: You can also use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` in your first query: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

Comment: Forget about 1 query, why is my 2nd query not giving me pagination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your only problem is the way you are trying to fetch total number of records. Set the SQL query to make the count and then retrieve it by reading the only row returned:

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) AS total_records FROM departments";
$rs_result = $db_connection->query($sql);
$total_records = $rs_result->fetch_assoc()['total_records'];
```

Comment: @cascaval : if my question was clear to you, please vote it so that it will be beneficially to the beginners like me.

Comment: By the way @cascaval,luigi : Can either one of you explain me, whats happening in the 3rd line in the above code,Please ..!! so that i can use it properly in coming days of my programming life

Comment: It's fetching one (and the only) row (`array`) of results the very same way as when you are fetching the records you are displaying. This row however contains only one column `total_records` which holds the total number of table records resulting from `count(*)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM departments";  //select query for total records
        $rs_result = $db_connection->query($sql); //run the query
        $total_records =$rs_result->num_rows;  //count number of records
```

Ok, you should select *. 
Select count(*) would return a single number (number of rows). //count number of records

Which is already being extracted later on.

Total records is select * from departments

Number of records is select count(*) from departments

Comment: Because of this.
$total_records =$rs_result->num_rows;
You're already pulling the wrong data from the database. That's why everything doesn't work anymore.

Comment: $total_records =$rs_result->num_rows; This line will always return a 1. everything falls off like a domino

Comment: Vokay. What i need to do to overcome it?

Comment: Again, change select count (*) to select * .
Look in your pagination you are using a variable $total_pages 
Which is being computed wrongly due to the $total_records being always 1.

If you don't want to pull the whole table just for the count. Then use Select count(*).
But then $total_records = $rs_result.
No need to num rows

Comment: Am not able to get you.Sorry!

Comment: Your query.. SELECT count(*) FROM departments
Is already your $Total_Records.
You don't need to use the number of rows as the value of $Total_Records. Gets?

Comment: $sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM departments";  //select query for total records

$rs_result = $db_connection->query($sql); //run the query

$total_records =$rs_result;  //NO NEED TO COUNT. you already counted in your query

$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $num_rec_per_page);

Comment: Sorry, try this

$temp_holder = mysql_fetch_row($rs_result);
$total_records=$temp_holder[0];

Comment: @ManiKandan If I helped.... even a little... I could use a vote.... just a little... vote... a tiny star... among the galaxy... far far away~